# Why Hindus worship Peepal Trees? (Ficus religiosa)

Tags: belief, worship, peepal-tree

I've often seen people, women especially, worship Peepal Trees ([Ficus religiosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_religiosa))

[image: Peepal tree worshipping by Hindus]

Why they do so? Is there any reason from Hindu scriptures behind doing that? As far as I know, people say that our ancestors' souls stay on those peepal trees, and hence we worship them. Is that explanation true, or is there some other reason behind rituals involving a peepal tree?

<sup>Credits for Image : http://kids.baps.org/</sup>

Comment: Note: The image shows women performing [vata-puja](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vat_Purnima) rituals around a *banyan* tree whereas the question is about Hindus worshiping peepal tree.

Comment: Thank you. I have been studying Trees and writing on them. In the Southern states the Month of Adi -usually July /Aug sees much regard and awareness of Nature as Shree Prakruti and esp Neem and Peepal are worshipped -esp on Fridays. Kind Rgds Capt.TR (Retd)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Brahma Purana and the Padma Purana, relate how once, when the demons defeated the Gods, Vishnu hide in the peepal. Therefore spontaneous worship to Vishnu can be offered to a peepal without needing his image or temple. The  [Skanda Purana](http://is1.mum.edu/vedicreserve/skanda.htm) considers the peepal to be a symbol of Vishnu. Vishnue is said to have been born under a peepal tree. Some believe that the tree houses the Trimurti – the roots being Brahma; the trunk, Vishnu; and the leaves, Shiva. The Gods are said to hold their councils under this tree, and so the tree is associated with spiritual understanding.

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_religiosa),

> The Skanda Purana states that the Sarasvati originates from the water pot of Brahma flows from Plaksa on the Himalayas. According to Vamana Purana 32.1-4, the Sarasvati was rising from the Plaksa tree (Pipal tree).
>
> Plaksa Pra-sravana denotes the place where the Sarasvati appears. In the Rigveda Sutras, Plaksa Pra-sravana refers to the source of the Sarasvati.

The peepal is also closely linked to Krishna. In the Bhagavad Gita, he says:
"Among trees, I am the ashvattha." Krishna is believed to have died under this
tree, after which the present Kali Yuga is said to have begun. And he will reside in a peepal leaf after *Pralayam* till the next world is created.

[image]

Five-trees (Pancha-vat) are considered sacred in India. They are:

1. Fig tree
2. A wild fig (Sycamore) tree (Gular)
3. Banyan tree
4. Pakar (citron-leaved), Indian fig tree
5. Mango tree

According to the [Skanda Purana](http://is1.mum.edu/vedicreserve/skanda.htm), if one does not have a son, the peepal should be regarded as one. As long as the tree lives, the family name will continue. To cut down a peepal is considered a sin equivalent to killing a Brahmin, one of the five deadly sins or *Panchapataka*. According to the [Skanda Purana](http://is1.mum.edu/vedicreserve/skanda.htm), a person goes to hell for doing so.

Some people are particular to touch the peepal only on a Saturday. The Brahma Purana explains why, saying that *Ashvattha* and peepala were two demons who harassed people. *Ashvattha* would take the form of a peepal and peepala the form of a Brahmin. The fake Brahmin would advise people to touch the tree, and as soon as they did, *Ashvattha* would kill them. Later they were both killed by *Shani*. Because of his influence, it is considered safe to touch the tree on Saturdays.

*Lakshmi* is also believed to inhabit the tree on Saturdays. Therefore it is considered auspicious to worship it. Women ask the tree to bless them with a son tying red thread or red cloth around its trunk or on its branches.

Ref:

1. [Skanda Purana](http://is1.mum.edu/vedicreserve/skanda.htm)
2. [Ficus religiosa(Peepal) : A Phyto-Pharmacological Review](http://ijpcsonline.com/files/53.pdf)