# Why do we worship ‘Tulsi’ plant and Peepal Tree?

Tags: worship

Why do we worship ‘Tulsi’ plant at homes and Peepal Tree at Temple

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the importance of the Tulsi plant (Holy basil)?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/159/what-is-the-importance-of-the-tulsi-plant-holy-basil) + http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/495/why-hindus-worship-peepal-trees-ficus-religiosa

Answer (score 0):

Various trees have been associated with various deities. Ashwatta or Peepal tree has been specially associated with Lord Krishna. In Gita (10.26), he declares that among the trees, he is the “Ashwatta”. Similarly, Rudraksha (meaning Rudra’s eyes) seeds are associated with Shiva, Banyan tree is associated with Brahma, Ashoka tree is associated with Kaama (God of Love) and Palasha tree is associated with Soma or Moon.

Almost all Hindu deities are associated with one plant or the other. This association must be understood properly. Trees like Peepal and Banyan are living representation of the Gods. Hence, those Gods can be worshiped directly through the trees without having to invoke Gods into an idol or fire. It is for this reason that Lord Krishna says he is the Peepal among the Trees, denoting that Peepal tree is home to Vishnu-tattva. Hence, a worship of Peepal is same as worshiping Vishnu in an idol.

Trees and plants can be worshiped as a direct manifestation of various deities, or as objects conducive to the worship of those deities. Another way of worshiping the trees is by showing reverence to their life-force.

You may like to read my full article on this- "Why we worship Trees?" here- http://www.newsgram.com/natural-oneness-why-trees-are-revered-in-hinduism/