# Good reason to plant Bodhi Tree (peepal) at home

Tags: plants, peepal-tree

I want to plant bodhi tree at home in my big plating pot, but my parents are not allowing me to do it. Please give me some good and strong religious reason to make them agree.
They are also saying ghost live there to scare me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Hindus worship Peepal Trees?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/495/5212) Peepal tree is said not to plant because it occupies more space and doesn't allow other plants to grow. It damages constructions nearby. Please visit [ask] page. Asking for users opinions is considered off-topic and gives rise to many opinions and partial answers. Please see questions under [tag:peepal-tree] and I am sure your doubts will be cleared.

Answer (score 5):

You can show your parents the [Aswattha Vriksha Stotram](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Aswatha_Vruksha_Stotram). According to which the tree itself is the abode of the Trinities (Brahma, Vishnu and Maheswara).

> Moolatho Brahma roopaya, madhyatho Vishnu roopine,
>  Agratha Shiva
>   roopaya Vruksha rajaya they nama., 1
>
> My salutations to the king of trees. Whose root is the form of Brahma,
>   Middle is the form of Lord Vishnu, And top is the form of Lord Shiva.

The other points that you can say in it's favor are that, if adored/taken care of, it is the bestower of riches, longevity, progeny etc, which all human beings love to possess.

Also, the presences of the deities in the tree will by itself take care of the fact that evil spirits don't wander nearby. So, your parent's apprehension is unfounded here.

See the various verses from the same Stotra given below:

> Ayurbalam yaso varcha, praja pasu vasooni cha,
>  Brahma prajnam cha
>   medham cha thwam nodehi Vanaspathe., 3
>
> Would you not give me, Oh product of the forest. Long life, fame,
>   splendour, children, cattle and riches, As also knowledge of God and
>   intellectual wisdom.
>
> Akshi spandham bhujaspandham duswapnam dhurvichinthanam,
>   Sathroonam cha samuthanam hyaswastha samaya Prabho., 5
>
> Oh Lord Aswatha, please control pain in the eye, Pain of hands, bad
>   dreams, bad and evil thoughts, And help me in destruction of my
>   enemies.
>
> Aswathaya varenyaya sarva aiswarya pradhayine,
>  Namo duswapna
>   nasaya, suswapna phala dhayine., 6
>
> Oh Aswatha who blesses us and grants all type of wealth, My
>   salutations to you, who destroys bad dreams and grants good dreams.

So, there are some good points you can recommend about the tree to your parents.

But having such a big tree in the compound of the house can be problematic as well and the garden should be quite big to accommodate it. The tree is extremely dominating so it will take control of the whole garden and it is likely to create wreckage in the surrounding walls too.